# How to create a new table based on fields from an existing table using SQL-Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I Just want to know how to create a new table based on an existing table column:

```
Current Table name : EmployeeDetails
Columns: empName, Address, pincode, state, city
Primary key is : pincode
```

I want to create the new table from EmployeeDetails:

```
New Table name : Information
column :pincode, state, city ---> from EmployeeDetails table
```

Comment: valid question but lots of similar questions have been asked before

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`select ... into`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx):

```
select  pincode
,       state
,       city
into    Information
from    EmployeeDetails
```

Comment: The `1 new answer has been posted to this question` showed up as I was moving the mouse to submit my *exact same answer*. The only difference was formatting of the SQL. :-) +1.